# Swift: CoreData call to specific object ID

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, core-data

I'm discovering new concepts as a fresh developer, I have been trying to understand core data, and run into an issue with a tutorial I've been walking through. I am getting an error when I call an item using the Object ID. The error is - **Type 'Person.Type' has no subscript members.** it may be because I am just not doing it correctly, or some other reason. I'm sure someone can shine some light on the subject

### Here is a function I wrote to get a specific item out of the Data Stack,

```
func getObjectById(id: NSManagedObjectID) -> Person?{
    return context.objectWithID(id) as? Person
}
```

### Here is how I am calling the function

```
func callFirstObject(){
    let context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
    let personService = PersonService(context: context)

    let firstPerson = personService.getObjectById(Person[0].objectID!)
}
```

and from there I am just calling `callFirstObject()` inside a button.

Edit: I have a function to call all of my objects

```
func getAllObjects() -> [Person]{
    return getObject(withPredicate: NSPredicate(value: true))
}
```

and a function to call all of my objects with a predicate

```
func getObject(withPredicate queryPredicate: NSPredicate) -> [Person]{
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: Person.entityName)

    fetchRequest.predicate = queryPredicate
    do {
        let response = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
        print("\(response)")
        return response as! [Person]
    } catch let error as NSError {
        // In case of failure
        print("There was an error - \(error)")
        return [Person]()

    }
}
```

I am just trying to call a specific name in the stack.

If more information is needed, I am glad to provide.

Answer (score 0):

Person has no subscript members because Person is the class name. The subscript, `[0]`, should be called on an array of Person objects.

That could look something like this:

```
func callFirstObject(){
    let context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
    let personService = PersonService(context: context)
    // Person Array
    let persons: [Person] = [person1, person2, person3 ]

    let firstPerson = personService.getObjectById(persons[0].objectID!)
}
```

Edit: I'm kind of confused the logic though. If you have the person already, you have to in order to access the objectID, then I don't see why you need to fetch it again. Can we see some more context around these two methods?

Answering your question from the comment below:

If you want to get all of the records for the Person model you can do as follows:

```
let appDelegate =
  UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Person")

do {
  let results =
  try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
  people = results as! [NSManagedObject]
} catch let error as NSError {
  print("Could not fetch \(error)")
}
```

This will give you all of the Person objects stored in Core Data

Comment: It is the class name you are correct, but the Entity in my .xcdatamodeld is called Person, is there some way i can call on that as an array? or does it not work like that? is there a way I can call the data model as a whole as an array? or do I have to make an array with a set amount of objects

Comment: @GabrielMSC see my edit above. That snippet will retrieve all of the Person objects as an array.

Comment: @GabrielMSC just saw you edit. Just so I'm clear, what is your end goal here? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Basically im just messing with CRUD, i want to be able to add names, display the names ive added to the list, edit those names, and delete them from the list.